# RegEx Lookarounds - Using own escape sequence

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm currently writing a little flatfile database for a project and in that context need to escape list item delimiters.

I decided to use ; as the delimiter and /; as my escaped version of that.

Since I already used RegEx lookarounds in the past, I was sure the following expression I use to split would do the job.

```
(?<!/);
```

My expression **should match** the ; in

```
abc;def
```

but **should not match** the ; in

```
abc/;def
```

I used RegExPal and the expression doesn't fit any of my examples.

Isn't this the correct structure of a regular expression to achieve my goal?

```
(?<!ForbiddenPreceedingExpression)CharacterFollowing
```

Any hints on where to find my problem?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? RegexPal is using the JavaScript regex flavor, which does not support lookbehinds.

Comment: That looks right to me. Are you sure your regex evaluator supports negative lookbehind groups though? While some (Perl, Python, Java) do with their native implementations do to a certain extent, many (e.g. Javascript) do not. If you know that your language does, it might also be an escaping issue.

Comment: Regex pal is a javascript regular expression tester. Java script **does not support** look behinds. Take a look at this https://regex101.com/r/yW8dM5/1 where as this one wont https://regex101.com/r/yW8dM5/2

Comment: Okay, that's the problem. I use Java and only used RegExPal to check it, but you are right, that was the problem. Anyone wants to write it as an answer?

Comment: What about `a//;b`, or `a///;b`?

Comment: How do you mean that? If I replace all ; with /; before saving the data and replace all /; with ; when I read them again, it should not matter, or did I get that wrong?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R If you add your comment as an answer, I can mark it as correct (for later visitors) and close the question. :)

Comment: What Kobi is essentially asking is: *how do you escape the escape character itself*? ie *what if you want to embed `/;` into the field value*? should `a//;b` evaluate to `a/` `b`? should `a///;b` evaluate to `a/;b`?

Comment: @Phiwa Done chief :)

Comment: @Kobi & Lucas Trzesniewski: Oh, I see. Any solution to that or isn't there any short one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the regex.

The problem is that  [**Regexpal**](http://regexpal.com/) is a javascript regular expression tester. **Java script does not support look behinds.**

Take a look at

[**pcre(php) Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yW8dM5/1)

where as this one won't

[**Javascript Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yW8dM5/2)